# Let $F$ be a CDF. Define $F_1^{-1}(x)=\inf\{y:F(y)\geq x\}$, and let $Z_1$ be the random variable $Z_1=F_1^{-1}(x)$. Find the CDF of $Z_1$

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the probability space $((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1),m)$, where $m$ is lebesgue measure.

Let $F: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a CDF.

For $0<x<1$ define $$F_1^{-1}(x)=\inf\{y:F(y)\geq x\}$$ $$F_2^{-1}(x)=\sup\{y:F(y)\leq x\}.$$

Let $Z_i$ be the random variables given by $Z_i=F_i^{-1}(x)$. Find the CDF of $Z_i$, $i=1,2$. (Hint; Verify, using right continuity of $F$, that for any $0<x<1$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $F(t)\geq x \iff F^{-1}_1(x)\leq t$)

Also show that $F_1^{-1}$ is left continuous and that $F_2^{-1}$ is right continuous.

I'm honestly pretty stuck on this one. Every time I try to dig into the problem, I find that translating between the definitions of $F_i^{-1}$ and $Z_i$, and then trying to obtain a CDF from that, is little dizzying and so I hit a road block.

If anyone has a gentle nudge (or a hefty shove) in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Or maybe there's a clearer way to think about this problem that would make the definitions a little less dizzying.

Thanks in advance.

Edit; To add a little more. I know that I'm ultimately looking for the measure of $Z_i^{-1}\left((-\infty,a]\right)$. I'm just repeatedly getting turned around, and so finding $Z_i^{-1}\left((-\infty,a]\right)$ is proving confusing.

Comment: $F_1^{-1}$ seems to be telling you where $F$ first hits the value $x$, and $F_2^{-1}$ tells you the last place where $F$ is $x$. So it seems like these two are the same unless there's a plateau. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yeah. That's how it seems to me.

I added an edit explaining that where I'm really struggling is just finding out what the set $Z^{-1}_i((-\infty,a]))$ is

Comment: So I think $Z_1 = 0$ for $a<0$, so we only need to worry about $a>0$. So we see that $\int_{0}^aZ_1(x)dx$ is just $-\int_{-\infty}^{F_1^{-1}(a)}F(x)dx+a\cdot F_1^{-1}(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_1^{-1},F_2^{-2}$ are somekind of "generalised" inverses of $F$.

Firstly, we'll show that $F_1^{-1}(\omega) \le t \iff \omega \le F(t)$

=> Suppose that $F_1^{-1}(\omega) \le t$. By definition of infimum and non-decreasing property of $F$, it means that for $h>0$ we have $F(t+h) \ge \omega$, but then by rightcontinuity of $F$ (and again, non-decreasing property) by taking $h \to 0^+$ we get $F(t) \ge \omega$.

<= Suppose $\omega \le F(t)$, then clearly $\inf\{s : F(s) \ge \omega\}$ is at maximum $t$ (because at point $t$ we're already we have $F(t) \ge \omega$)

Then, letting $Z_i = F_i^{-1}$, we see that on probability space $((0,1),\mathcal B((0,1)),m)$, by looking at distribution function of $Z_1$, we have:

$$ F_{Z_1}(t) =  \mathbb P( \{ \omega \in (0,1) : F_1^{-1}(\omega) \le t\}) = \mathbb P( \{ \omega \in (0,1): \omega \le F(t) \}) = m((0,F(t)]) = F(t) $$

Hence, $Z_1$ is distributed with CDF $F$. (Really analogous proof of $F_{2}^{-1}(\omega) \le t \iff \omega \le F(t)$ I'll left for you, having that you can proceed similar with $$ F_{Z_2}(t) = \mathbb P(\{ \omega \in (0,1) : F_{2}^{-1}(\omega) \le t\}) = \mathbb P(\{\omega \in (0,1) : \omega \le F(t)\}) = m((0,F(t)]) =F(t)$$
getting that $Z_2$ is also distributed accordingly to CDF $F$.

As for the second part with continuity, let's start with $F_1^{-1}$. Take any $s \in \mathbb (0,1)$ and $h >0$ such that $s-h >0$

We need to prove $F_1^{-1}(s-h) \to F_1^{-1}(s)$ as $h \to 0^+$.

Assume contrary, that there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that $F_1^{-1}(s) - F_1^{-1}(s-h) > \varepsilon$ for all $h>0$ such that $s-h > 0$. (we using monotonicity of $F$ here) But since $x=F_1^{-1}(s)$ is fixed, we would have for all $h>0$ such that $s-h > 0$ that $ F_1^{-1}(s-h) < x - \varepsilon$, hence $s-h \le F(x-\varepsilon)$ Letting $h \to 0$ we would get $s \le F(x-\varepsilon)$ hence $x=F_1^{-1}(s) \le x-\varepsilon$, a contradiction.

Similarly for right continuity of $F_2^{-1}$. Take any $s \in (0,1)$ and $h>0$ such that $s+h < 1$. We need to prove $F_2^{-1}(s+h) \to F_2^{-1}(s)$ as $h \to 0^+$.

Assume contrary, that there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that $F_2^{-1}(s+h) - F_2^{-1}(s) > \varepsilon$ for all such $h$ (again, we used monotonicity of $F$ (and hence of $F_2^{-1}$)). Similarly $x=F_2^{-1}(s)$ is fixed, so that we get inequality:
$ F_2^{-1}(s+h) > x+\varepsilon$ which is equivalent (we prooved above $F_i^{-1}(x) \le t \iff x \le F(t)$, but it's equivalent with $F_i^{-1}(x) > t \iff x > F(t)$) to $s+h > F(x+\varepsilon)$. And letting $h \to 0$ we would get $s \ge F(x+\varepsilon)$ and hence $x=F_{2}^{-1}(s) \ge x+\varepsilon$, a contradiction.

So $F_1^{-1}$ is left, and $F_2^{-1}$ is right continuous.

Note that at first glance it might seem that we didn't use right continuity of $F$ while proving one-hand-side continuous of $F_i^{-1}$. But we did! Use of right continuity of $F$ is the "lemma" we proved, that is $F_{i}^{-1}(x) \le t \iff x \le F(t)$

Comment: This explanation was exceptionally clear; Bounty awarded.

Thanks a bunch for your answer, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the important thing to note is that $F_1^{-1}(x)$ and $F_2^{-1}(x)$ both just look like $F(x)$ flipped around the line $y=x$; in particular, they're exactly the same except where $F$ plateaus, and at these points $F_1^{-1}$ and $F_2^{-1}$ have to make a vertical jump, $F_1^{-1}$ is just the flipped version of $F$ where we pick the bottom of the vertical strip as the value, and $F_2^{-1}$ is the version where we pick the top point. If you draw a picture of some $F$ with a plateau, and then flip it around the line $y=x$, you'll see immediately that the stated continuity conditions are essentially obvious. Also, we see that this choice of endpoint doesn't affect the measure in any way, so we actually don't really care which version we're talking about. Finally, after drawing a little picture, I believe you should arrive at: $$\int_{-\infty}^aZ_i(x)dx = \int_0^aZ_i(x)dx = a\cdot F_1^{-1}(a)-\int_{-\infty}^{F_1^{-1}(a)}F(x)dx = a\cdot F_2^{-1}(a)-\int_{-\infty}^{F_2^{-1}(a)}F(x)dx$$
Let me know if anything isn't clear or if I've stated something completely false!